# How to use AWS Cognito in HANA OnPrem DB for user authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, hana

I have set up a Cognito User Pool with several Users in AWS. Besides a HANA Onprem DB is running on an EC2 instance in the same AWS Account.

I can't find a way to use Cognito directly in HANA DB to e.g. connect to HANA via python-backend (hdbcli), instead of username and password, using ID Tokens to authenticate.

Cannot find information in SAP Docu how to configure Cognito as Identity Provider in HANA Studios. A few articles in SAP Docu can be found, that describe step by step how to integrate Cognito to HANA Cloud. But we are not using HANA Cloud, we are using HANA DB OnPrem running in an EC2 instance.

Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: `HANA Onprem DB is running on an EC2 instance in the same AWS Account` why such weird setup when we have https://cal.sap.com/? is it purely research scenario?

Comment: Cause we are using AWS as Cloud and HANA DB as database only.

Comment: got it, I missed that it is simple HANA DB w/o S4